# Handle deadlock in C# Service

Tags: c#, service

I have one service in C# which fetch records from oracle DB and insert into MySql DB, after a successful insert of all records in MySql DB one of the column of my Oracle DB gets an updated i.e these many records has got inserted.

Since being a service it's getting called after every 5 sec.

My problem is that how should i handle the deadlock situation in this case. Like my service fetches around 20,000 records from oracle DB and trying to insert in to MySql DB that takes around 7-8 seconds, mean while my service will get called, and since all records of previous session are not getting inserted there won't be update in Oracle DB and next time it will again fetch the whole records, that i don't want.

If possible provide some same code as well. This is pure Window base service not WCF.

Comment: Is this service a WCF service?  If so, you can set the concurrency to ensure that calls are processed one at a time, which should address your issue.

Comment: @Grant H : No, not WCF Service.

Comment: Then what kind of service is it?...

Comment: @GrantH. - it's probably a Windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need "coordination" only in this service then use *AutoResetEvent* class.

1. Create static field with *AutoResetEvent* instance.
2. Your method called by timer should check this instance via *AutoResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout)* call on start.
3. At the end of your method (called by timer) **always** call *AutoResetEvent.Set()*. *try{} finally{}* construction usually is ok for this call.
4. During starting of your service call *AutoResetEvent.Set()* for created instance to allow the method (called by timer) start
   working.

Using of *WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout)* with small timeout allow to finish timer "call" quickly if previous one is not finished yet.. So you still get ability to call you methods each 5 s.

Sure checking about AutoResetEvent disposing will be needed before call its methods and maybe some additional checks...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your functional requirements are, but it sounds like you don't really want to start processing in your service until after any previous run has been completed.  i.e. You need some kind of system for saying whether an exiting run is in progress, and then check this before starting a subsequent process.
Another option would be to queue requests, then process them as a batch, effectively removing duplicates.

Comment: right before start new process i want all the previous one should get finished first.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to wait for the insert into Oracle to complete, therefore queue your requests in c#, i.e. do them synchronously. Look into using a Mutex object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a few options here.

1. Don't run the service as frequently, especially if it's not really necessary. You say you have a service picking up 20,000 records every 5 seconds - that seem pretty frequent for anything that size.
2. Issue a lock on the Oracle table until the update is completed so that all read operations would have to wait.
3. Don't start-up the service delegate on a timer but rather on an event. So, when you first started the service you would fire the event by hand, but every raised event thereafter would come after the update completed.

Personally I would prefer option #3.

Comment: being the service it will get called automatically after every 5 Sec, since this is the requirement. so, i just want to know what is the event which updates me that previous process has finished and now processed.

Comment: @Sham - you can't safely run it blindly every 5 seconds. You're going to have to build this into your service. I don't know how your code base is structured but in short you need to **call the method that starts the process** both ***when the service first starts*** and then call that same method ***when the update is complete***. If that means you need to build a custom `event` then do that, otherwise it may be as simple as a method call. But doing it this way ensures that it won't get started unless the update is finished.